# C99 in VS2010: uint8_t* illegal use of type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c99

I am using VC2010, trying to compile some library written in C99 for Linux. The following line gives error C2275: 'uint8_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression

```
uint8_t * G = (uint8_t*)calloc(N ,sizeof(uint8_t));
```

subhint: stdint.h(21) : see declaration of 'uint8_t', and that line is:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

and then come the accumulated problems: error C2065: 'G' : undeclared identifier etc. What is illegal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar question was already answered:
[error C2275 : illegal use of this type as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903582/error-c2275-illegal-use-of-this-type-as-an-expression)

**Answer:**
When you name your source files *.c, MSVC assumes it's compiling C, which means C89. All function-local variables need to be declared at the beginning of your functions.

Workarounds include:
 - declaring/initializing all local variables at the beginning of your
   function
 - rename the source files to *.cpp or equivalent and compile
   as C++.