# unable to build netifaces

Tags: c, visual-c++, python-2.7

I am trying to build python netifaces for windows. I am using microsoft visual c++ express 2010 edition. When I run the command python setup.py install I get the following log and errors:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing netifaces.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to netifaces.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to netifaces.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /
W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32=1 -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.8 -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\py
thon27\PC /Tcnetifaces.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\netifaces.obj
netifaces.c
netifaces.c(410) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expr
ession
        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
netifaces.c(411) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expr
ession
        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
netifaces.c(720) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expr
ession
        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
netifaces.c(720) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(722) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(722) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'PyObject *'
netifaces.c(724) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(734) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(734) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of
 indirection from 'int'
netifaces.c(734) : warning C4024: 'PyDict_SetItemString' : different types for f
ormal and actual parameter 1
netifaces.c(736) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(736) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of
 indirection from 'int'
netifaces.c(736) : warning C4024: 'PyDict_SetItemString' : different types for f
ormal and actual parameter 1
netifaces.c(738) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(738) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of
 indirection from 'int'
netifaces.c(738) : warning C4024: 'PyDict_SetItemString' : different types for f
ormal and actual parameter 1
netifaces.c(744) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
netifaces.c(744) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of
 indirection from 'int'
netifaces.c(744) : warning C4024: 'add_to_family' : different types for formal a
nd actual parameter 3
error: command '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' f
ailed with exit status 2
```

sorry for the bad formatting
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Rename netifaces.c to netifaces.cpp (and update the setup.py accordingly).

The reason is that with .c extensions, MSVC interprets these files as adhering to C89, which netifaces.c does not follow; more info here:
[error C2275 : illegal use of this type as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903582/error-c2275-illegal-use-of-this-type-as-an-expression)