# Haven't been able to install netifaces

Tags: pip, windows-10, python-netifaces

I've been trying to install netifaces in Windows 10, unsuccessfully. This was my input in the cmd:

```
 C:\Users\usuario\Downloads\SonOTA-master\SonOTA-master>pip install netifaces
```

This was the response by the cmd:

```
Collecting netifaces
Using cached netifaces-0.10.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: netifaces
Running setup.py install for netifaces ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 45: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
spinner=spinner,
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 45: invalid continuation byte
```

Looking if others were having this issue I searched and found a Stackoverflow article addressing it:

see link: ([unable to build netifaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350507/unable-to-build-netifaces))

There's an answer that says:

"Rename netifaces.c to netifaces.cpp (and update the setup.py accordingly)".

I don't know how to do this renaming process because I didn't download any netifaces.c file. I just wrote the input "pip install netifaces", so I don't know how to rename a file this way.

I'm no expert but I'm 100% willing to learn. If its a dumb question, sorry. This is also my first stackoverflow question post. If I have not done it properly, please let me know and next time I'll do it better.

I've seen you guys are really helping tons of people at helping them solve their problems, together as a community. Huge props for that.