# C Struct pointer issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm constructing a linked-list, and this is the list item Struct:

```
struct TListItemStruct
{
    void* Value;
    struct TListItemStruct* NextItem;
    struct TListItemStruct* PrevItem;
};
typedef struct TListItemStruct TListItem;
typedef TListItem* PListItem;
```

I use this in several function and it looks ok so far. However when I define the following variable:

```
PListItem item;
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2275: 'PListItem' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Why is that? What's wrong with defining a variable of type pointer to struct?

EDITS:
This is more of the function. This doesn't work

```
BOOL RemoveItem(PListItem item)
{
    // Verify
    if (item == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Get prev and next items
    PListItem prev;
    prev = item->PrevItem;
    //PListItem next = (PListItem)(item->NextItem);
 ...
```

However this works:

```
BOOL RemoveItem(PListItem item)
{
    PListItem prev;
    // Verify
    if (item == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Get prev and next items
    prev = item->PrevItem;
    //PListItem next = (PListItem)(item->NextItem);
 ...
```

I'm using VS2012, maybe it's a standard thing? to declare vars in the beginning of the function?

Comment: Your problem might be somewhere else in the code causing this specific variable declaration to be parsed incorrectly.

Comment: This is a C, C++ problem. The pointer "this" doesn't exist on C, which compiler are you using? What extension is your file? Can you show some more code?

Comment: Seems like it's because I've declared the vars in the function body and not right on start. Is this a C issue?

Comment: Yes, before C99 I think, try moving them to the top of the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903582/error-c2275-illegal-use-of-this-type-as-an-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC uses C89, it does *not* support C99, so you need to either declare all variables at the beginning of your function or compile as C++.

Comment: @RavindraBagale `this` is a keyword in C++

Comment: @Cicada it is still a possibility, no ? I've added the error from MSDN anyway

Comment: @mux:in question that was not a keyword, it showing because of SO's parser

Comment: @Cicada yes I get the syntax highlighting thing :) was just saying, anyway I removed that and just left the example

Answer (score 1):

In C89 (which is supported by Visual Studio 2012) you have to declare variables at the beginning of the scope. That's why your latter example works fine.