# error C2059: syntax error : 'type'

Tags: c

I've got error:

```
main.c(10) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'.
```

What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getline(FILE* file, char* line)
{
    int c;
    size_t n = 0;
    while(c=fgetc(file)!='\n')
    {
      line[n++] = char(c);
    }
    line[n] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* f;
    char* line = (char*)malloc(100);
    f = fopen("Saxo","r");
    if(f==NULL)
      return -1;
    getline(f,line);
    free(line);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A C++monster should know that :) Just kidding, no offence. Post the whole error description, please.

Comment: should be `line[n++] = (char)c;`

Comment: Oh god sorry for stupid question. It's now ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line[n++] = char(c);` is a syntax error. I guess you meant to cast:

```
line[n++] = (char)c;
```

NB. This cast actually has no effect, as `int` can be implicitly converted to `char`, which happens anyway because `line[n++]` has type `char`.

It would also be wise to check against `EOF` as well as `\n` in your loop, in case the file does not end with a newline.

Also: `=` has lower priority , so the line `while(c=fgetc(file)!='\n')` is going to set `c` to either `1` or `0`. Some parentheses required to fix.

Comment: Are you sure, it's a syntax error? Because it's not in C++.

Comment: No, if you would like to pore over the grammar for a while, we could clear up whether it is a syntax error or a constraint violation..:)

Comment: I don't argue, I'm asking just out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering your name this probably is a confusion since C++ allows what are called [explicit type conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) which are an expression:

```
line[n++] = char(c);
```

so this would compile fine in C++ but this does not exist in C so what you need to use is a plain cast:

```
line[n++] = (char)c;
```

but is not necessary in this case.

I would advise cranking up the warnings that would have indicated that this line is a problem:

```
 while(c=fgetc(file)!='\n')
```

`clang` warns us by default while `gcc` does not:

```
 warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
while(c=fgetc(file)!='\n')
      ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
while(c=fgetc(file)!='\n')
       ^
      (                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

> You might be using a version of C that doesn't allow variables to be declared in the middle of a block. C used to require that variables be declared at the top of a block, after the opening { and before executable statements.

Already have a discussion from here

[error C2275 : illegal use of this type as an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903582/error-c2275-illegal-use-of-this-type-as-an-expression)

and here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/693b03be-4198-4abc-8717-92c91f868437/error-c2059-syntax-error-type?forum=vclanguage