# Mex file in Matlab : error

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I am trying to use SLIC superpixel matlab code.
The source code contains .c files. After using 
 *mex -slicmex.c*

The following errors appear :

*slicmex.c 
slicmex.c(108) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(109) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(123) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(126) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(171) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(172) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(173) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(174) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(386) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(387) : error C2275: 'mwSize' : illegal use of this type as an expression 
        C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\extern\include\tmwtypes.h(792) : see declaration of 'mwSize' 
slicmex.c(387) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'numdims' 
slicmex.c(387) : error C2065: 'numdims' : undeclared identifier 
slicmex.c(393) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data 
slicmex.c(445) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data*

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'slicmex.c' failed.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Comment: you can probably ignore the warnings (although it's not clean code) and focus on the errors. Specifically the error at line 387 of slicmex.c. What is at that line?

Comment: Also other question, which compiler do you use to compile the mex file?

Comment: At line 387 it exists this instruction


 mwSize numdims = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]) ;

Comment: the compiler is [1] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0

Comment: can you comment that line out and try again?

Comment: @AbdelkhalekBakkari I found an interesting post on this problem. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903582/error-c2275-illegal-use-of-this-type-as-an-expression) helps.